# After upgrading to WP 5.1.1 sometimes I need to reauth infinitively

Tags: admin, authentication

I have some blogs, and after upgrading to 5.1.1 I always have to reauth myself. If password/username is wrong, I got that error message but if I enter right data, the page simply reloads.
So I go to:

https://www.example.com/wp-admin

it then redirects to:

https://www.example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1

and even I enter the right account data, it just reloads the site.

Of course, clearing all browser data helps - but next day, this bug occurs again. I dont think its a good solution to clear my browser everytime when it happens.

EDIT: Its Php 7.3 and nginix

EDIT2: I added this line to my config:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

so far works well. I dont know what it is by the way.

Comment: did you migrated from non https to https?

Comment: the old one was also https

Comment: read [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131304/unable-to-login-to-my-wordpress-site-reauth-1-redirection-loop-any-ideas-on-ho) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/264070/redirect-loop-when-trying-to-login-to-wp-admin)

Comment: hmm yea, after adding "define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);" it let me in...

Comment: try renaming your .htaccess file as .htaccess1 and let wordpress create fresh one for you. goto admin->settings->general and see in there you have correct https urls for both Site URL and Home

Comment: unfortunately its nginx so I dont have .htaccess file

Comment: re-examine your nginx config file then. anyhway, if your problem is fixed, you can add answer to your own question so it'll help someone else